# wcf decision: one service multiple contracts or many services

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I am using .NET 4 to create a small client server application for a customer. Should I create one giant service that implements many contracts (IInvoice, IPurchase, ISalesOrder, etc) or should I create many services running one contract each on many ports? My questions specifically is interested in the pros/cons of either choice. Also, what is the common way of answering this question?

My true dilemma is that I have no experience making this decision, and I have little enough experience with wcf that I need help understanding the technical implications of such a decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't create one large service that implements n-number of service contracts.  These types of services are easy to create, but will eventually become a maintenance headache and will not scale well.  Plus, you'll get all sorts of code merging conflicts if there's a development group competing for check-ins/check-outs.

Don't create too many services either. Avoid the trap of making your services too fine-grained.  Try to create services based on a functionality.  The methods exposed by these services shouldn't be fine-grained either.  You're better off having fewer methods that do more.  Avoid creating similar functions like GetUserByID(int ID), GetUserByName(string Name) by creating a GetUser(userObject user). You'll have less code, easier maintenance and better discoverability.

Finally, you're probably only going to need one port no matter what you do.

UPDATE 12/2018
Funny how things have changed since I wrote this.  Now with the micro-services pattern, I'm creating a lot of services with chatty APIs :)

Comment: If using partial class/interface files to avoid merging conflicts, what about the argument "will not scale well"? What does it mean technically?

Comment: @Askolein...It means if you have too much stuffed into a single contract it can become a performance bottleneck as well as a maintenance/extensibility headache.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my question was more  "why" could it be a performance issue not "what" is a performance issue.  You say "bottleneck": I understood that in ISS/WCF each web request is a new Service instance. Multiple requests on one single big service would still be multiple instances, not one instance serving all of them. So no scaling issue. Is this reasoning right?

Comment: @Askolein...If some methods are more resource intensive then others, they may have a negative performance impact on the others and the service as a whole.  When factored into a separate service- contract/web site, this risk is easily handled.

Answer (score 2):

In real time applications you have one service contract for each entity like Invoice, Purchase and SalesOrder will have separate ServiceContract

However for each service contract there will be heterogeneous clients like Invoice will be called by backoffice through windows application using netNamedPipeBinding or netTcpBinding and same time client application needs to call the service using basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBindings. Basically you need to create multiple endpoints for each service.

Answer (score 2):

You would typically create different services for each main entity like IInvoice, IPurchase, ISalesOrder.

Another option is to seperate queries from commands. You could have a command service for each main entity and implement business operations accepting only the data they need in order to perform the operation (avoid CRUD-like operations); and one query service that returns the data in the format required by the client. This means that the command part uses the underlying domain model/business layer; while the query service directly operates on the database (bypassing the business, which is not needed for querying). This simplifies your querying a lot and makes it more flexible (return only what the client needs).

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that you are mixing between DataContract(s) and ServiceContract(s).
You can have one ServiceContract and many DataContract(s) and that would perfectly suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that splitting up WCF services - or any services is a balancing act. The principle is that you want to to keep downward pressure on complexity while still considering performance.

The more services you create, the more configuration you will have to write. Also, you will increase the number of proxy classes you need to create and maintain on the client side.

Putting too many ServiceContracts on one service will increase the time it takes to generate and use a proxy. But, if you only end up with one or two Operations on a contract, you will have added complexity to the system with very little to gain. This is not a scientific prescription, but a good rule of thumb could be say about 10-20 OperationContracts per ServiceContract.

Class coupling is of course a consideration, but are you really dealing with separate concerns? It depends on what your system does, but most systems deal with only a few areas of concern, so splitting things up may not actually decrease class coupling that much anyway.

Another thing to remember, and this is ultra important is to always make your methods as generic as possible. WCF deals in DataContracts for a reason. DataContracts mean that you can send any object to and from the server so long as the DataContracts are known.

So, for example, you might have 3 OperationContracts:

```
[OperationContract]
Person GetPerson(string id);

[OperationContract]
Dog GetDog(string id);

[OperationContract]
Cat GetCat(string id);
```

But, so long as these are all known types, you could merge these in to one operation like:

```
[OperationContract]
IDatabaseRecord GetDatabaseRecord(string recordTypeName, string id);
```

Ultimately, this is the most important thing to consider when designing service contracts. This applies for REST if you are using a DataContract serialization like serialization method.

Lastly, go back over your ServiceContracts every few months and delete operations that are not getting used by the clients. This is another big one!

Answer (score 0):

You should take the decision based the load expected, extensibility needed and future perspective. As you wrote " small client server application for a customer" it is not giving clear idea of intended use of the development in hand. Mr. Big's answer must be considered too.

You are most welcome to put forward further question backed with specific data or particulars about the situation in hand. Thanks.